# Time virtualisation on linux

Tags: linux, testing, time

I'm attempting to test an application which has a heavy dependency on the time of day. I would like to have the ability to execute the program as if it was running in normal time (not accelerated) but on arbitrary date/time periods.

My first thought was to abstract the time retrieval function calls with my own library calls which would allow me to alter the behaviour for testing but I wondered whether it would be possible without adding conditional logic to my code base or building a test variant of the binary.

What I'm really looking for is some kind of localised time domain, is this possible with a container (like Docker) or using LD_PRELOAD to intercept the calls?

I also saw a patch that enabled time to be disconnected from the system time using unshare(COL_TIME) but it doesn't look like this got in.

It seems like a problem that must have be solved numerous times before, anyone willing to share their solution(s)?

Thanks
AJ

Comment: What exactly is your heavy dependency on the time of day? Do you have the entire source code of the application? In which language is it written?

Comment: It's c++, I do have access to the entire source. Heavy dependency in the sense that in numerous parts of the code the current date time is being retrieved and needs to be in sync with the historical data that is being supplied for a given test run.

Answer (score 3):

Whilst alternative solutions and tricks are great, I think you're severely overcomplicating a simple problem. It's completely common and acceptable to include certain command-line switches in a program for testing/evaluation purposes. I would simply include a command line switch like this that accepts an ISO timestamp:

```
./myprogram --debug-override-time=2014-01-01Z12:34:56
```

Then at startup, if set, subtract it from the current system time, and indeed make a local `apptime()` function which corrects the output of regular system for this, and call that everywhere in your code instead.

The big advantage of this is that *anyone* can reproduce your testing results, without a big readup on custom linux tricks, so also an external testing team or a future co-developer who's good at coding but not at runtime tricks. When (unit) testing, that's a major advantage to be able to just call your code with a simple switch and be able to test the results for equality to a sample set.

You don't even have to document it, lots of production tools in enterprise-grade products have hidden command line switches for this kind of behaviour that the 'general public' need not know about.

Answer (score 1):

There are *several* ways to query the time on Linux. Read [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html); I know at least [time(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/time.2.html), [gettimeofday(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gettimeofday.2.html), [clock_gettime(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html).

So you could use [LD_PRELOAD tricks](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/simple-ld-preload-tutorial/) to redefine each of these to e.g. substract from the seconds part (not the micro-second or nano-second part) a fixed amount of seconds, given e.g. by some environment variable. See [this example](https://www.ilikejam.org/blog/2011/02/ld-preload-hackery.html) as a starting point.